# Mutation null return GraphQL

Tags: node.js, graphql, backend

I'd like to make a simple mutation that adds a "group" to my local database.

However the mutation returns me NULL.

```
mutation {
  addGroup(
    image: "image"
    name: "nom"
    description: "descr"
  ) {
    code
    message
    groupId
  }
}
```

Here is the code controller:

```
const addGroup = async ({ name, description, image }) => {
   try {
        await addGroups(name, description, image);
      } catch (e) {
        return { code: 500, message: "Database error", groupId: 4 };
      }
      console.log("ok");
      return { code: 200, message: "ok", groupId: 5 };
};
```

Here is the models and schema :

```
const addGroups = (name, description, image) =>  
  pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO groups (name, description, image) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
  [name, description, image]
  );
```

```
  type Link {
    code: String
    message: String
    groupId: ID
  }

  type Mutation {
    addGroup(image: String!, name: String!, description: String!): Link
  }
```

Comment: GraphQL doesn't have the concept of controllers, but resolvers. Can you show me how your schema be constructed?

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer, you can find my schema in my question

Comment: If `addGroup` is never called, then there's most likely something wrong with how you're passing in your resolvers to whatever is creating your schema (Apollo Server, makeExecutableSchema, etc.). Please show all the relevant code -- the question can't really be answered with just the code you've provided.